# Laravel Hesto multi-auth NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use Hesto multi-auth to make multiple authentication. I made controllers, routes and others, but when I try open url e.g. localhost:8000/student/register it throws NotFoundHttpException.

This is example of route

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'student.' . env('APP_DOMAIN')], function () {
  Route::get('/login', 'StudentAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
  Route::post('/login', 'StudentAuth\LoginController@login');
  Route::post('/logout', 'StudentAuth\LoginController@logout');

  Route::get('/register', 'StudentAuth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
  Route::post('/register', 'StudentAuth\RegisterController@register');

  Route::post('/password/email', 'StudentAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
  Route::post('/password/reset', 'StudentAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
  Route::get('/password/reset', 'StudentAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
  Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'StudentAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
});
```

And this is exception

```
in RouteCollection.php line 179
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('F:\\Studia\\Sem 3 mgr\\Praca magisterska\\thesis_system\\public\\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` to see all routes laravel knows about. Maybe there is a prefix or something else

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have only defined path for `/register` on a domain `student.<your-app-domain>`, but in your request the domain is `localhost` and the path is `/student/register`, so it does not match any of the path definitions.

Comment: By making sure the domain and the path matches.
Option a) Make your request match the routes: create a fake domain like `student.myapp.dev` and add that to your hosts file (replace `myapp.dev` with whatever is actually the value of ENV variable `APP_DOMAIN`) and request `http://student.myapp.dev/register`
Option b) Make your definitions match your request - set the domain to be `'localhost'` (without any `APP_DOMAIN` stuff), and make your paths to be prefixed with `/student` where necessary, e.g. `Route::get('/student/register', <...>`

Comment: From the project website:
To be able to use this feature properly, you should add a key to your .env file:

APP_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
Go to: http://url_to_your_project/guard/login Example: http://project/admin/login

Comment: Not sure what I should do with this info? Is it me or you who's trying to solve a problem?

Comment: I only show instruction. It should work, but it doesn't.